# How to put a Map/JSON object containing array values into local storage

Tags: javascript

I want to store the following into local storage with a structure like so:

```
{
  "stuff": [
    {
      "user1": {
        "numbers": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      },
      "user2": {
        "numbers": [
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your structure is invalid. An array doesn't contain key/value-pairs. Could you fix the structure?

Comment: @3limin4t0r i've updated the question

Answer (score 2):

to save

```
localStorage.setItem("name",JSON.stringify(Map));
```

to read

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"));
```

Comment: I have tried just doing JSON.stringify(Map) and it is persisting  as {} meaning its showing up as empty for some reason

Comment: Your object need to be like `[{"userID1": [1, 2, 3]}, {"userID2": [1, 2, 3]}]` and if problem is Map then try to change its name

Comment: For me too, it is not stringifying the Map object. It is stringinfying as {}.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
    (() => {
  // ok
  const map = new Map();
  map.set(1, {id: 1, name: 'eric'});
  // Map(1) {1 => {…}}
  localStorage.setItem('app', JSON.stringify([...map]));
  // undefined
  const newMap = new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app')));
  // Map(1) {1 => {…}} ✅
})();
```